# Spring WebFlux - How to return response from middle of the stream?

Tags: functional-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying to deal with a scenario where I want to return from the middle of the stream (mono/flux) with some default response based on some predicate (condition). For example:

```
end-result = flux
.step1()
.step2(some predicate -> return some dummy end-result from here and skip further execution)
.step3()
.step4(//returns end-result);
```

I am not able to figure out way to do so, as WebFlux is a pipeline in nature, whatever I do at step 2 is a feed to step 3, I am not able to avoid it going further.

I understand there are certain ways with *flatMap(obj -> some-predicate(obj))* to write a code in if-else fashion, but I am looking for something which is available out of the box and works in functional way.

Comment: you cant return in the middle, you need to make sure that all steps can handle the data you are passing. Because coding that way is not secure, type safe or functional.

Comment: you need filter here. use a filter and then in `switchifempty` or `defaultIfEmpty` return your default response

Comment: Is not hard to achieve what you want but I would need some more context about `step3` and `step4`, at least what they need as input and what they produce as output. I would say `.apply`, `.doOnSuccess`, `doOnNext` operators would be helpful.